# Is it possible for a heading <h1> to be wider than parent div?

Tags: html, css

The main body of my web page is contained inside a `<main>` element. This has a `max-width:800px` and is centered `margin:0 auto`.

Is it possible for the heading `<H1>`, within the `<main>` to be wider than 800px – to have a `max-width:1000px` by protruding out of the `<main>` by 200px on the right hand side?

See image:
[image]

I undertstand I can give the heading `position:absolute` and then `max-width:1000px` but the trouble with this is that the text below the heading is then displayed behind the heading (because the heading has been taken out of normal flow). Is there a way to use `position:absolute` AND for the height of the heading to be respected?

Comment: What happens when you try? The answer is "Yes"...this issue is how you attempt it and what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi JoshKisb. The position: absolute does enable the heading to be wider than the container - but because it is taken out of normal flow the text below the heading goes behind the heading. I'm new to this. So please bear with me. How do I stop my content from being displayed behind the heading?

Comment: Add a padding to the top of main - the content will shift below the heading. Of course - if your heading wraps, this will still be a problem. I would use another div around the content and add 200px padding to the right of that and make main 1000px

Comment: Yes in smaller browser windows the heading will wrap. I'm not too sure what you mean by your second suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try width adding a negative margin to the heading.

CSS:

```
 h1 { 
     margin-right: -200px;
     max-width: 1000px;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't really work. When the browser window is made smaller the right hand side of the heading disappears. I need the heading to wrap on to other lines, i.e. a max-width.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible and your luck smiled upon you ;)
Here is an example code:

```css
.main-container {
  position: relative;
    width:100%;
  background: grey;
 }
 .main-content {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
 }
 .yellow {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
 }
 .h1-wrap {
  position: relative;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
  background: cyan;
 }
 .h1-wrap > h1 {
  position: relative;
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 125%;
    background: transparent;
  z-index: 99;
 }
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="main-content">
   <div class="h1-wrap">
    <h1>Some texts outside of .h1-wrap <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo nesciunt voluptatem vel, nam, veniam autem ullam quisquam minima doloremque quae obcaecati molestiae deserunt sapiente fugiat. Laudantium nisi saepe, totam harum! lorem</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <h1 class="yellow">Another text relative to .main-container</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I don't know the height of the heading or the text below it. And I don't want a fixed width for the heading - it has to be be max-width, so that it will shrink when viewed in smaller browser windows. Unfortunatly when we remove the height and width, this no longer works. see https://jsfiddle.net/1655ky1d/

Comment: Also, the trouble with the negative margin trick is that the heading can disappear off the sides of  the brower window.

Comment: @Makeee, check again the snippet above and see if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Markee, mobile friendly website needs media queries implemented. I may do it for you, but I have to be sure if we are on the right track.

Comment: Terribly sorry but I don't think you are on the right track

Comment: Then, it seems what you are looking for is either impossible or you are not reconsidering your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161486/discussion-between-catapultedplastic-and-markeee).

Comment: I'm coming to realise that it is not possible using html and css. That I need javascript to add padding to the top of the main container that is equal to the changing height of the heading (as the heading reflows on to numerious lines at smaller sizes).